How to make a 3D carousel responsive on mobile
I'm having an issue to make 3D carousel responsive on mobile. I tried adding img-fluid class using Bootstrap but it messes my web view.
Below is css code in html


var angle = 0; 
    function galleryspin(sign) { 
    spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
    if (!sign) { angle = angle + 45; } else { angle = angle - 45; }
    spinner.setAttribute("style","-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ angle+"deg); -moz-transform:rotateY("+    angle +"deg); transform: rotateY("+ angle+"deg);");
    }
div#carousel { 
    perspective: 1200px; 
    background: black; 
    padding-top: 10%; 
    font-size:0; 
    margin-bottom: 3rem; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
figure#spinner { 
    transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    height: 300px; 
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px; 
    transition: 1s; 
} 
figure#spinner img { 
    width: 40%; max-width: 425px; 
    position: absolute; left: 30%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
    outline:1px solid transparent; 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(1) {
    transform:rotateY(0deg); 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(2) { 
    transform: rotateY(-45deg); 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg); 
 }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(4) { 
    transform: rotateY(-135deg);
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(5){ 
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(6){
    transform: rotateY(-225deg);
 }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(7){
    transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(8){
    transform: rotateY(-315deg);
 }
div#carousel ~ span { 
    color: #fff; 
    margin: 5%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size: 2rem; 
    transition: 0.6s color; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: -6rem; 
    border-bottom: none; 
    line-height: 0;
}
div#carousel ~ span:hover {
    color: #888; cursor: pointer; 
}
<body>
  <base href="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div id="carousel">
  <figure id="spinner">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt>
  </figure>
  </div>
  <span style="float:left" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('-')">&lt;</span>
  <span style="float:right" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('')">&gt;</span>
</body>



I read online that I can make a mobile view website by adding some code. Is that true, can I make it responsive just by that or do I need Bootstrap?

seems fine on desktop and mobile

it looks fine on desktop but on mobile it doesnt fit the image when moving the slider some pictures fit but others are only showing a portion of it

You Can first try to decrease your perspective in small screen ie 400px

Do you mean this?: example
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {transform: rotateY(0deg)}
    to {transform: rotateY(360deg)}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CSS Animation</h1>

<div></div>


</body>
</html>

